# Delete character in string that matches any character in another string

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to create a squeeze function that deletes each character in string `s1` that matches any character in the string `s2`.

When I compile, it doesn't say that there are any errors, however nothing is being printed out for some reason. Could someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly here?

```
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main() {
    char s1[] = "abc";
    char s2[] = "cde";
    squeeze(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\t%s", s1, s2); // nothing is being printed...
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i,j,k; 
    /* i is original s1 index
     * j is s2 index
     * k is new s1 index
     */

    for (i = k = 0; s1[i] != '0'; i++){
        for (j = 0; s2[j] != '0'; j++){
            if (s1[i] == s2[j])
                s1[k++] = s1[i];
        }
    }

    s1[k] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `!= '\0'` is what you intended. `'0'` is the digit zero, not the nul terminator.

Comment: I rhink you meant to use `'\0'` in the loops instead of `'0'`. Your program is probably crashing.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick :)

Comment: By the way you could use https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn to help implement this if you want.

Comment: Please, post http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve examples... don't post code pieces that don't compile.  How can we check if your code compiles ok (as you say in your question) if you don't post a complete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error due to placement of '0' instead of '\0' in second term of for condition. Even that correction is made the output is "c" for s1 instead of "ab" as required. The following code gives the required output "ab" for s1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);
int isCharPresent(char c, char s[]);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char s1[] = "abc";
    char s2[] = "cde";
    char * s = squeeze(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s", s, s1, s2);
    return 0;
}

char * squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int i, k;
    char *s = malloc(sizeof (s1));
    for (i = k = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isCharPresent(s1[i], s2) == 0) {
            s[k++] = s1[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int isCharPresent(char c, char s[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (c == s[i]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```